# Mongoose how to join search result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an article model defined as following:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    type: String
    ,title: String
    ,content: String
    ,hashtags: {
        type: [String]
        ,index: true
    }

    ,meta: {
        tags: [String] //anything
        ,category: String
    }
```

Now I need to do search by category, by tags and by keyword.

```
    var words = queryString.split(' ')

    if (searchType === constant.searchTypes.category) {
        criteria['meta.category'] = {$in: words}
    }
    else if (searchType === constant.searchTypes.tag) {
        //todo
    }
    else if (searchType === constant.searchTypes.keyword) {
        //todo
    }

    var query = Article.find(criteria)
    helper.populateCommonFieldsForQuery(query)
    query.exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err)
            return next(err)
        return res.json(articles)
    })
```

the queryString is simply in 'word1 word2 word3' format. Searching by category is easy since one article only has one category. I can simply use $in premise.

But article has multiple tags, I want to list all articles with any of their tags match any of query words (i.e. set intersect is not empty)

Also I need to do search by keyword, which I need to check either title or content match. Can I do that in one query?

Answer (score 0):

`criteria['meta.tags'] = {$in: words}` expression can be used for `tags` too. And `$or` operator can be used for querying title and content values.
MongoDB official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/

Actually the question is not clear for me. There are if conditions for `searchTypes`. 
If the conditions were not I would prefer the below code (I didn't test it);

```
var words = queryString.split(' ')
var criteria = $or[
    { 'meta.category': {$in: words} },
    { 'meta.tags': {$in: words} },
    { title: {$in: words} },
    { content: {$in: words} },
]
var query = Article.find(criteria)
helper.populateCommonFieldsForQuery(query)
query.exec(function(err, articles) {
    if (err)
        return next(err)
    return res.json(articles)
})
```

And indexing the the all queried fields should not be skipped.

Good luck.

Comment: but tags field is an array. both title and content are long string.

Comment: tags is working. but content is not working since it's not tokenized

Comment: `$or` operator just performs logic `or` process like this `$or[expression1, expression2, ..]` and if an expression value is ` true` it returns true. So, appropriate documents are returned. Another issue must be there about `content`. If you cannot solve the issue edit your question adding some sample documents from your MongoDB and your code which is used if different with the questions'. I'll try to help you.